# Marker, InfoWindow and Shadow not rendering correctly in Google Maps Javascript API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I copied the Google Maps AutoComplete JS example from the demo here:

[Places Map AutoComplete Demo](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete.html)

Everything works great except for rendering the infowindow and shadow. I can't figure out why. At first I thought it was because of I manually set the max width of my map, but it still renders incorrectly when I turn off all my CSS rules.

### **Here is an example from my client-side code:**

[image]

### **Here is a screenshot from the demo**

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks!
~Dan

@thoughtpunch

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Had the same problem, debugging revealed the problem to be with the following CSS snippet:

```
img { max-width:100% }
```

Removing/constraining the rule fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for this. This problem occurred for me because I was using the twitter bootstrap css and it had this rule in it. 

To fix this without changing the incriminating stylesheet just adding another rule: img { max-width : none }